Is there a way to override a Mac system font
I am using Avenir Next Condensed.ttc which is a Mac system font. This is my client's brand font.
My Mac OS and my Adobe software are all up to date.
The problem is most definitely in Adobe Acrobat, not in InDesign, PDFs written from InDesign and opened in Preview look perfect. A PDF saved from Word and opened with Acrobat shows the same rendering problem. I have been in communication with Adobe for a week now and ultimately they just said that Avenir Next Condensed is a restricted font and they can't offer support.
The lowercase 'u' X height is higher than all the other lowercase letters.

How can I install a .ttf or .otf version of the font in FontBook and override the Mac system font?
I have tried installing a .ttf version but it seems that InDesign always uses the Mac system font version.

I think at this point, after dealing in depth with Adobe, Monotype and Mac and getting very informative replies on 3 different community support sites, I have to give up. The Avenir Next Condensed supplied as a Mac system font has this rendering problem and no-one can do anything about it. Everyone has offered workarounds but they are not viable for my situation. I've let me client know the options and will move forward based on their preference.

Have you tried using the LT Pro version? (TBH, most designers forbid using system bundled fonts, particularly for a brand logo or style.)

I played around a bit: PDF export from Pages seems to be ok, export from LibreOffice or Word not. But if I zoom the Word PDF to 400% in Acrobat, all lowercase characters have the same height?!

I guess the other option is to ask your client to use a different PDF viewer, like Foxit Reader.

Can you provide the exact reply from Adobe, because "Avenir is a restricted font" doesn't really mean anything.

@benwiggy The response was given to me over the phone. Adobe worked on a sample PDF that I sent them and then worked on my computer. They tried pulling the .ttc version into "added fonts" in Creative Cloud, it would not accept it and threw up the message "this is a restricted font". Thereafter Adobe says that they do not offer support for this font because it is restricted. These PDFs are for an international organization and will be viewed globally. I inherited the brand guidelines, their designer chose Avenir Font Next Condensed, not the Pro version, they won't pay for Pro.

I found their final email to me, which was as follows: "However, we looked into the issue that you were facing. We tried our level best to provide you with a workaround for the same on fixing the Avenir Next Condensed font which is a restricted font on Adobe However we tried to check with the file format of the apple font which was not supported as well Hence we kindly request you to contact the apple support" Of course Apple won't provide me with a font. I have not been able to find a version of Avenir Next Pro Condensed that I do not have to pay for to test with. Monotypewould not help.

And finally: I got a very informative response on the Apple Community Support platform: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255587202?answerId=260392058022&sortBy=best#260392058022

Kurt Lang is the man on fonts.  I've just looked at the hinting in FontLab, and it's much more widespread, affecting nearly every glyph. Simplest solution is to update the brand using another similar font -- ideally not a bundled font. I'll report the hinting issue to Apple, for all that it's worth.

@benwiggy Thanks for all your very useful responses and information! I am discussing with my client how they want to move forward, now that there is a lot more information I can give them on why this is happening.

You can't disable system fonts.
There have been problems with bundled system fonts taking precedence over other versions, since Apple first made some fonts un-removable back in Leopard.
This particular problem seems to have been reported widely over the internet (and not all of it by Yelda55..!) for a few years, with no solution. It seems to affect the screen rendering of the letter u in Adobe products. It only appears at certain zoom sizes, and doesn't seem to affect printing.
As the inestimable Kurt Lang has pointed out, the TrueType hinting data in these system bundled fonts does seem to be complete wrong.
The usual solution is to use a different version with a different font name, such as Avenir Next LT Pro. Though that is expensive.
You could also try converting the .ttf font to .otf, which uses different hinting algorithms.
Outlining the font with either Acrobat or GhostScript might produce better results, though the PDF's text can't be edited.

It has been possible to 'override' what Apple calls 'legacy document fonts', which are bundled with the system but can only be used in existing documents, not new ones. If you open the .ttc font in a font editor and save individual .ttf copies to the user font library, this allows the OS to use these fonts normally. I don't know whether a similar operation would work; but of course it requires anyone who wants to view the PDF to have custom fonts.

It's a shame, because Avenir Next is one of the best Geometric Sans faces out there.

Microsoft Office comes with a downloadable „Avenir Next LT Pro“ TrueType font which gets stored in ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/FontCache/4/CloudFonts/Avenir Next LT Pro. I‘m not sure about the licensing situation, but if you have Office installed you could at least try whether it yields better results.

NB: It comes with the 365 subscription, not with one-time purchases of Office.

Thanks for the tip, I do have a subscription, but I need Avenir Next Condensed and that is not supplied with Word, as far as I know.

@nohillside That doesn't look like a legal site.

@benwiggy Probably, but the OP could at least check whether it works correctly. Would expect the OP to do some research.

@nohillside I've been in communication with Monotype, Adobe and Mac for almost two weeks. Thanks for your input!

@Yelda55 If my remark sounded aggressive, sorry, that was not the intention. I‘m aware of your interactions with the various vendors, must be frustrating if they can‘t offer a solution. Nevertheless, it may very well be that the version Apple distributes has a bug which only shows under certain circumstances. In that case, using another source might help.

@nohillside No worries! It's been a learning experience!
